# Running Nuxt3 on a specific path only

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I struggle to get my app working with static deployment with Nuxt.
I would like to deploy the static files to "test" subdirectory of my website ([www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test)).

When I run "npm run generate", it generates a ".output/public" directory with files I copy to the "test" folder of my production server. But I get 404 errors when doing that: my index.html file in the public folder references files in the root folder of my website (extract):

```
<meta name="head:count" content="2">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/_payload.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/entry.8af327a9.js">
```

As you can see, the page is looking for js files in the root directory instead of /test directory.

Here is my nuxt.config.ts with router config:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    target: 'static',
    css: [
        '~/assets/global.scss'
    ],
    router: {
        base: '/test/'
    }
})
```

I tried also to set up public_path to "/test" but it does not work either. Is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: What is running on the rest of your website?

Comment: I started a new Nuxt3 app from Scratch (simple App.vue "test" message) and can't get it to work on a subdirectory. After changing baseURL as suggested below, index.html is still looking for _payload.js file in root directory instead of "/test/" directory

Comment: Maybe try that one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/5070 Otherwise, here is the official answer: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/1525#discussioncomment-2363692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the base URL in `nuxt.config.js|ts`:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    baseURL: '/test/'
  }
})
```

See: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config#baseurl

Comment: Thanks for your proposal and the link! I tried to update my config with it and it still fails. Index.html is still looking for _payload.js at root and not "/test/" subdirectory (Chrome error: "GET https://www.example.com/_payload.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 Not Found"). I changed the BuildAssetsDir property but it does not work either. Any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: You might be hit by https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/7806. Wait for the next RC or try the edge channel: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/edge-channel/